# Android : Gradle computes wrong apk name

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew, android-studio-2.0

I am renaming my apk file using following code :

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            android.defaultConfig.versionName = variant.mergedFlavor.versionName;
            renameAPK(variant, defaultConfig)
        }

def renameAPK(variant, defaultConfig) {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def formattedDate = new Date().format('ddMMMyy')
        def applicationName = "Myapp"


        def alignedFile = output.outputFile
        def unalignedFile = output.packageApplication.outputFile

        def fileName = applicationName + "_" + defaultConfig.versionName + "_" + variant.buildType.name + "_" + formattedDate


        //If there's no ZipAlign task it means that our artifact will be unaligned and we need to mark it as such.
        if (variant.buildType.zipAlignEnabled) {
            fileName = fileName + ".apk"
            output.outputFile = new File(alignedFile.parent, fileName)
        }
        fileName = fileName + "-unaligned.apk"
        output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(unalignedFile.parent, fileName)


    }
```

This works fine in most cases. However, occasionally, I get an error when trying to install the app on a device which says :

> Gradle build finished in 1s 615ms 12:37:04 PM EmptyThrowable: The APK
>   file ./build/outputs/apk/Myapp_4.0_debug_18Apr16.apk does not exist on
>   disk.

The problem is that in such cases, the date used by Gradle is wrong. If I run gradle script from command line, it generates an apk with correct date.

However, if I choose "run" from Android Studio, gradle computes wrong file name.

I have tried Invalidating cache and restarting Android Studio. And also, cleaning project and rebuilding. Nothing solves this problem 100% of times.

Has anyone else encountered this before?

Comment: thats gradle glitch, just clean your project and restart android studio. It will all work well. Well it does with me thousand times.

Comment: Year 2019, i have the same issue. After i have used this `output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", " " + getDateTime() + ".apk"))`, when changing flavors and updating, i got these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Using an APK name with a timestamp or dynamic counter do not work very well (depending on change rate) because Android Studio keep APK name in cache.
Either AS run an outdated file or complained about no APK

Answer (score 0):

Go to project directory under aap folder delete the generated files and delete the apk file if existed build and run again..hope this helps

Comment: Try to build the Apk from Build in Android studio , i ran into same problem it solved